# running react native , server returned error

Tags: react-native

```js
import React from 'react';
import {
  Image,
  Platform,
  ScrollView,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
} from 'react-native';

export default class HomeScreen extends Component<{}> {
  render() {
    return (
      <view style={styles.container}>
        <Text> My Name Is John </Text>{' '}
      </view>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    background: 'blue',
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});
```

```
//I got this error below
```

> The development server returned response error code: 500
>
> URL:
> [http://packager.ep-qma.akinolajohn.blanco.exp.direct/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&strict=false&minify=false&hot=false&assetPlugin=C:\Users\OLUWAGBEMIGA\Desktop\John%20Akinola\blanco\node_modules\expo\tools\hashAssetFiles](http://packager.ep-qma.akinolajohn.blanco.exp.direct/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&strict=false&minify=false&hot=false&assetPlugin=C:%5CUsers%5COLUWAGBEMIGA%5CDesktop%5CJohn%20Akinola%5Cblanco%5Cnode_modules%5Cexpo%5Ctools%5ChashAssetFiles)
>
> ```
> Body:
> {"type":"TransformError","snippet":"  22 |  }\n  23 | \n> 24 | const styles = StyleSheet.create({\n     |       ^\n  25 |
> ```
>
> container:{\n  26 |     background :'blue',\n  27 |     flex:
> 1,","lineNumber":24,"column":6,"filename":"C:\Users\OLUWAGBEMIGA\Desktop\John
> Akinola\blanco\screens\HomeScreen.js","errors":[{"filename":"C:\Users\OLUWAGBEMIGA\Desktop\John
> Akinola\blanco\screens\HomeScreen.js","lineNumber":24}]}
> processBundleResult
> BundleDownloader.java:239
> access$100
> BundleDownloader.java:42
> execute
> BundleDownloader.java:171
> emitChunk
> MultipartStreamReader.java:69
> readAllParts
> MultipartStreamReader.java:116
> onResponse
> BundleDownloader.java:159
> c
> RealCall.java:135
> run
> NamedRunnable.java:32
> runWorker
> ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133
> run
> ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607
> run
> Thread.java:761

Answer (score 0):

Try this code below, you forgot to close the export tag :

```js
import React from 'react';
import {
  Image,
  Platform,
  ScrollView,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
} from 'react-native';

export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <view style={styles.container}>
        <Text> My Name Is John </Text>{' '}
      </view>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    background: 'blue',
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});
```